# search and replace commented linux config lines

Tags: sed

I want to change commented line in config files from command line usind sed.
for instance, the line

> #xllForwarding no

is coommented. i want to uncooment it and change the value to yes.
how can i do it best practice?

example to a line i tried:

```
  sed -r 's/^#[ *] passwordAuthentication.* /passwordAuthentication no/' sshd_config
```

It didn't work.
note there might be spaces( 0 or more) between the # sign and the configuration name

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `/^#[ *] passwordAuthentication.* /` to `/^# *passwordAuthentication .*/'` and it'll work. You don't need the `-r` as that's a BRE and so will work as-is in all seds. Get a tutorial on regexps.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like:

```
sed -r 's/^[ \t]*#[ \t]*(.*)no[ \t]*$/\1yes/g;' file
```

It matches a whole line (`^` and `$` ensure that the re spans a complete line) consisting of

1. optional whitespace `[ \t]*`
2. a `#`
3. another optional whitespace `[ \t]*`
4. something `(.*)` captured into `\1`
5. `no`
6. optional whitespace at lineend `[ \t]*`

The replacement reuses `\1` (everthing following (the optional whitespace) after the `#` up to the `no` and then puts `yes` behind.

Comment: This is a Dangerous Solution, because it can change lines where the config value is nobody for example.

Comment: @student the `no` is anchored at the lineend with the `$`. Between the `no` and the lineend is only an optional whitespace `[ \t]*` allowed. A line ending with `nobody` will not match and nothing will be changed.

Comment: You don't need the global `g` flag here, as this regex will always match the whole line, so there can't be multiple substitutions.